# How to reuse symbol/data defined in .bss section?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, elf, reassembly

So basically I am trying to re-use some assembly code/data dumped by `objdump` from 32 bit ELF binary on Linux.

So basically, in the disassembled binary, I found some symbol referring to `.bss` section like this:

```
 80486b7:   mov    0x804b264,%eax   <- 0x804b264 is an addr in .bss
 80486bc:   movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
 80486c3:
 80486c4:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80486c7:   call   804876c <sum>
```

By digging into the original source code, I find out that `0x804b264` is used for `stdin` in `.bss` section.

IMHO, there are basically two situations on `.bss` section's data:

1. uninitialized data, will be uninitialized in the source code
2. some global/system related data (such as **stdin** in the above situation)

So when trying to re-use `.bss` section's data, I have tried this way:

```
.section .bss
S_0x804B260 : .byte 0x00
           .byte 0x00
           .byte 0x00
          .byte 0x00
S_0x804B264 : .byte 0x00          <- I lift addr into symbol!
          .byte 0x00
         .byte 0x00
         .byte 0x00
         .byte 0x00
```

and in the `.text` section, I will also lift corresponding addr into symbol.

**same situation works fine for `.rodata` and `.data` section**

But the problem is that, there are some global variables (such as **stdin** **stdout**), locating in `.bss` section, while are not initialized by **user defined code**, which means that in my re-used asm code, this symbol variable will always be **zero**!

I tried to manually substitute symbols corresponding to **stdin**, and it seems that it works fine.

But the problem is that:

1. How can I identify which symbol in the `.bss` section is some variables that initialized by system? such as **stdin**, *stdout** and others?
2. If it is not possible, then is there anyway that I can enforce system to use memory in the `.bss` section where I want it to use?

Am I clear? Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're not too clear when you talk about "reusing" some part of a program. What exactly do you want to do? Load the original program into a debugger, then call just one single function of it? Extract a ranged of addresses and turn that into a new program? Or extract one function from the original program, possibly together with everything the function depends on, then embed that function into a larger program?

You're wrong in one thing: the .bss section is NOT initialized at all at program start (at least not to anything but a load of `\0` bytes). The initialization of stuff like `stdout` is done in runtime before main() starts. Stuff that gets initialized with constant data goes into the .data segment.

(On a side note: One of the reasons why the stdout FILE structure isn't put into .data and initialized as constants is most runtimes on unix-like systems will check if their file descriptor goes to a terminal or something else, and turn on/off buffering depending on that check).

When you extract a part of the code, you'll have to check each reference to .data AND .bss (and to .text - the code - as well if the extracted part depends on any libraries etc.). For each of those references, you'll have to decide what to do with them - share them with the new program, keep them for the functions you extracted, whatever.

If you're lucky, and have an unstripped executable, you can use `nm` to find out which symbol is where; if you're not that lucky, you'll have to disassemble/decompile everything, understand it, rewrite it into new source, and compile it together with whatever you want to embed it in.